# What kind of router would you use to extend a cabinet opening?

Tags: cabinets, routers, custom-cabinetry

I'm the proud owner of this guy:

http://www.cabinets.com/dsmw649h-mbc24-shaker-maple-bright-white-microwave-base-cabinet-1-drawer.html

The description is as follows (emphasis mine):

> 1 bottom drawer, 1 shelf included SHIPPED LOOSE with no shelf clips,
>   the shelf is intended to be field installed to help hold the
>   microwave, this cabinet is intended for built in microwaves not
>   countertop microwaves, must field install microwave, this cabinet does
>   not have finished interior, cut out dimensions are 14 13/16" high by
>   17 3/4" wide, **maximum cut out is 15 13/16" high by 20 7/8" wide**,
>   premium UV finished plywood cabinet box construction, 1/2" plywood
>   hanging rails, 5/8" solid maple english dovetail drawer box with BLUM
>   motion integrated easy-close slides

​What kind of router and bit is warranted here in order to cleanly and straightly expand the hole?

Comment: Does your microwave come with any kind of a template?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't gotten the microwave yet, but from its specsheet, I will have to cut the cab and I'm not sure which tool to use to do it right.

Comment: It sounds like since there is already an opening and you'll just have to enlarge it a regular fixed router with a straight cutting bit could be use to open the hole. Depending on the material exactly, a downcut bit could make a nicer finish. I don't know that I'd use a mini or trim-router.

Comment: Complicated answers -- whew! Cut close to the line with a jigsaw so you aren't taking too much with the router. Get a top bearing straight cutter (1/2" shank and cutter preferred, but whatever you've got...) Hot glue / carpet tape sticks to the outside (run each corner long in the same direction so you don't have to cut anything accurately). Router-router-router. Square your corners if needed. Reading this entire page took longer than the cutting operation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Straightly** has entirely to do with your fence/guide, and there are many ways to do that. You can fence the baseplate, use collars and fence those, or use bearing bits and fence those - it's just a matter of offset from the cut line.

**Cleanly** is trickier, and depends on where you need clean. Solid wood trim would allow you to cover your sins, while trying to get a perfect cut on both sides of plywood might lead you to a (usually comparatively expensive) double-spiral (upshear and downshear on the same bit) to cut both faces into the middle.

[image: Image from Amazon]

A upshear from the backside or a downshear from the face side is most typical, but may result in tear out on the backside. Unless your guests look at the inside of the cabinet *which should be hidden by the microwave being in it* seeking tearout, no-one will ever know but you, normally.

I do wonder if the opening is already framed in solid wood strips, looking at the illustration. That would make it much less prone to tearout.

[image: from cabinets.com link in OP]

Comment: Yes.  The cabinet material will be a huge part,  Also I would practice.  Even after using my router 100 times I still mess crap up all the time, less so if I do a practice run right before the real thing.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you using a router?  Does your microwave overlap the edges?  If so, I'd **use a jigsaw**, seems to me to be much easier set up.

Comment: Great point! I should have specified I wanted to use this as an opportunity to learn to use the proper tool in case the cutout was not hidden.

Comment: @Matt - You can play with your router on your own time. Use a jigsaw ;)

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with a router would be in the corners they will be rounded not totally square. A very small straight bit would give the smallest Chamfer (non square). This last fathers day my wife bought me [this set of router bits](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ROUTER-BITS-SET-35-pc-1-2-inch-Shank-CARBIDE-KIT-ALUMINUM-CASE-SAE-New/311651442817?_trksid=p2141725.c100338.m3726&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20150313114020%26meid%3D6e062ec82ea549f380d0346eee6b10af%26pid%3D100338%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D22%26sd%3D311645542233) I thought oh boy how long are these going to last I usually spend 15-20 per bit. The ones I have used have worked well, I mention this because you could a small bit in the corner then a larger one for the longer cuts.  Make sure to use a guide or with a bearing tipped bit have some shims so you get the cut you want.

Comment: Your wife knew what kind of router bits to get you?  Holy crap +1 to the wife!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean want to expand the rectangular front cut out, and not some other hole. I think most hand-held routers would do the job. There is no need for a plunge feature in this operation, but you will want to guide the router along a straight edge to do a good job.

My first choice would be downward spiral ¼" straight bit, to eject the wood chips from the cut, in combination with a router template guide. This would allow you to follow a straightedge (e.g. straight board) clamped to the outside of the cabinet.

A normal ball-bearing guided straight flute bit could also work. These can be obtained with ball bearing guides on the top (or bottom) of the bit. The ball-bearing guide would allow you to follow a straightedge (e.g. straight board) clamped to the outside (or inside) of the cabinet.